# Twitter Bootstrap strange behavior, joomla 3.0

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have a weird behavior of bootstrat in my joomla 3.0.

First the drop-down didn't work, so I've found this [tread](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=718&t=769849) and update a bootstrap. It seemed as it fixed the problem on desktop, but when I try to shrink the page to mobile with, the menu start's acting strange, Work's only one's and when I streach back the screen the menu don't apper...

Any suggestion's how to fix it?

Here's my [page:](http://www.turdidesigns.com)

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap 2 or bootstrap 3?

Comment: I've downloaded the lastest from [link](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/) and it sais version 2.3.2